# Absolute position div

Tags: html

Okay i'm trying to center some content, but, I want to keep the absolute attribute to keep the content within a certain height on the page, but at the same time, i want the content perfectly centered. How do I center it if absolute takes specific coordinates? Everyone has different sized monitors so giving the coordinates to center it will fail.

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: do you want to position that `absolute` `div` to `center` of the page or you want some content to be `centered` in that `div`

Answer (score 3):

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Make the left position 50% and then give it a negative margin to pull it back by half the width.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/utiqod/2)

Comment: @user1511404 because those links take you to the demo pages to show you the thing you want